# How can I modify an Excel worksheet so that it shows only 10 lines including the bottom tabs?

Tags: excel, tabs

I would like to modify an Excel worksheet so that it reflects only 10 lines, as I want to transfer this 'shortened' worksheet to a document.  It does however have to include the bottom tab, which is  "Week 1".  An attempt of mine is attached - I used snipping tool "twice" to get the result - obviously not the way to achieve the result I desire.  Could anybody perhaps help?  [image: Capture1]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need to do is resize the window to get what you want

[image: resize the window]

Comment: Many thanks, I noted there is in fact a resize button top right corner.